# How to insert record to the table that has a before insert trigger without violating a constraint?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

What I desire: to reset value of sequence sq_nxtval on failure to insert

What I did:

```
create sequence sq_nxtval
start 1
increment 1;

create table tbl_nxtval(
a int default nextval('sq_nxtval'),
b int,
constraint tbl_nxtval1 check (b = 1)
);

create or replace function fx_nxtval () returns trigger as
$$
begin
    perform setval('sq_nxtval',currval('sq_nxtval')-1);
    return null;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger tg_nxtval
before insert on tbl_nxtval
for each row
execute procedure fx_nxtval ();
```

Then I Tried this: to insert a value complying with a constraint

```
insert into tbl_nxtval (b) values (1);
```

Result:

```
Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 76 ms execution time.
```

Then I checked the current value of sequence

```
select currval('sq_nxtval');
```

Result: 1

My expectations here in this first example were a value must be inserted to table `tbl_nxtval` and the trigger won't execute.

Then I tried this: to insert a value not complying with a constraint

```
insert into tbl_nxtval (b) values (2);
```

Result:

```
Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 25 ms execution time.
```

Then I checked the current value of sequence

```
select currval('sq_nxtval');
```

Result: 1

My expectations here in this second example were a value wont be inserted to table tbl_nxtval and the trigger executes.

- What are the problems here?
- Did I made wrong use of triggers?
- What different approaches should I do to reset value of sequence?